# Unable to set environment variables using source ~/.profile in script

Tags: environment-variables, bash

So I have a script, and I'm setting an environment variable using:

```
echo 'export env_var=hello' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

When the script completes, I check the existence of this environment variable by doing:

```
echo $env_var
```

Which gives me "" rather than "hello". If I run source ~/.profile on my terminal (typed straight up in the terminal, not called from any script) , the environment variable will be set correctly. Why is my script unable to set the environment variable correctly, and what do I need to do for it to do so?

Comment: `env_var` becomes only available in the subshell that script is executing in. script cannot make something available in parent shell.

Comment: Now, if you have added to `~/.profile`, the new `env_var` will be available to the *next* login shell where  `~/.profile` will be sourced setting up the shell.

Answer (score 0):

`env_var` is being `export`-ed all right, but in the subshell (and its children) the script is being executed on.

When you execute an= script, the script is run on a subshell, which is a child of the calling shell, so after the script finishes, the exported variables go out of scope from calling shell's point of view.

A common practice to have all the variables (and other data structures) available in the calling shell, is to `source` (`.`) the script, not execute it, which you are doing but from the script, not from the interactive session.